# Formula field in Opportunity to populate Opportunity Line Items

Tags: opportunity, formula-field, lookup, master-detail, opportunity-lineitem

I have given a requirement of populating the Opportunity Line Items in a formula field in Opportunity Object. But i find it unable to write the formula for this as ***Opportunity Line Items And Opportunity*** shares a **LookUp Relationship** ...

Is there anything i am missing here. Kindly suggest any approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be achieved by formula.

Through formula, we can only traverse from child to Parent. Reverse is not possible.

Salesforce maintains special kind of relationship for Account-Contact and Opportunity-OpportunityLineItems.

Though those relationships are defined as lookup but behave as Master-Detail. That's why they are **special**.

You could create a field and write a trigger to populate the field.